# Firefox. InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Tags: javascript, firefox, push-notification, web-push

Firefox 62.0.2 (64 bit). Windows 7 x64. Write code from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients) in firebase-messaging-sw.js of our site:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
    event.waitUntil(async function() {
        throw "1";//this line for debug only
    }());
});
```

Code raise exception "InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable" in Firefox on the event.waitUntil(). In Chrome work normally. Why? How I can fix it?

P.S. I am looking for the answer of the second day. :(

Comment: so this is in a service worker, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is service worker

Comment: Did you find a fix? Getting this issue with a Vimeo player.

Answer (score 6):

Had this problem in Firefox 63. And in Chrome everything is working fine. My service-worker code was:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    'messagingSenderId': '...'
});
var messaging = firebase.messaging();

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
...
}
```

I accidentally found this: [stopImmediatePropagation in firebase-messaging.js](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/102#issuecomment-278584863).
I moved my event-listener in the beginning of my service-worker (before importScripts):

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
...
}

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.6/firebase-messaging.js');
```

And the handler started working in Firefox.

P.S. Handler started working fine, but after this manipulation the error was thrown by firebase-messaging library. event.stopImmediatePropagation() helped:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
...
}
```